# mysql add constraint - #1005 - Can't create table ... errno: 121 Duplicate key on write or update

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have been pulling my hair on this one and I am sure it is something small that I can not see...

Here are my 2 tables companies and peoples with many to many relationship and my pivot table company_people :

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_active` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `company` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `peoples` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_active` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `firstname` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `company_id` bigint UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci PACK_KEYS=0;

CREATE TABLE `company_people` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `company_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `people_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `companies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `peoples`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `company_id` (`company_id`);

ALTER TABLE `company_people`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  ADD KEY `people_id` (`people_id`);

ALTER TABLE `companies`
  MODIFY `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `peoples`
  MODIFY `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `company_people`
  MODIFY `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `peoples`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `peoples-company` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `company_people`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `companies-peoples` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `company_people`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `peoples-companies` FOREIGN KEY (`people_id`) REFERENCES `peoples` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Everything goes except the last mysql statement which gives the following error : #1005 - Can't create table `FairTrade`.`company_people` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Where is the glitch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in

```
ALTER TABLE `companies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `company_id` (`company_id`);
```

get so

> Error Code: 1072. Key column 'company_id' doesn't exist in table

so remove the key like

```
ALTER TABLE `companies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ;
```

or choose another column

Comment: I agree there is an error if you run this code but it is because I remove the company_id definition in the table companies by mistake.  Run the code again and you will see the other error.

Comment: i run rhis  code in my mysql 8.0.23 and it runs without problem, so which version exactly are you running of mysql.

Comment: thank you @nbk. If I ran the code on an empty db, there is no error but if I try to run the foreign key constraints on existing tables with clean data, i get the error...

Comment: look i can't follow you see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6009c1e08b32f6c6c2695a4f846f24cb change it, so that it makes the error